# Block to Popup Page, on demand?

Tags: pages

I have embedded HTML in a block which renders a Python console.
What I want to do is to be able to pop-out the Block in a separate window.

If that is not possible then may be a link that when I click on it pops-up a page that contains the console.

How do i do that ?

---

I don't want the pop-up to be full-screen. I want to be able to move it around, so the text below can be seen.

The HTML can be anything, I just give it as example. Let say :

```
<div id=ABC>12345</div>
```

---

i know js/html/css but no idea of how wp works...

Do i just embed html link with onclick=window.open(...) pointing to a wp-page ?
Ooo but i have to somehow make it pure page i.e. no theme !! HOW?

And second i have to hide ABC !

---

Got it : https://myriad.website/create-popup-window/

here is working : https://myriad.website/learn-python/

dont look at the site ... it is still under construction ;)

Comment: What is the console? How does it work? What’s the HTML?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you want the block to appear full-screen. You could make it a link, which links to a particular page/post/cpt on your site - and that page/post-cpt would need to have a custom theme template. The custom template would call `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` but in between only output the HTML, so the only thing on that page would be the console, no header/footer/etc. You might need to output a stylesheet for that template to force the console to appear full-screen.

Comment: how do i make it popup

Comment: @sten there is no code in your question, but I also don't believe WordPress knowledge will be useful to you here. Generic frontend HTML/CSS/JS knowledge is what you need

Comment: i know js/html/css but no idea of how wp works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it : https://myriad.website/create-popup-window/

here is working : https://myriad.website/learn-python/

First install the “Blank Slate” plugin.
Create New Page
Leave the Title empty
Set in Page property Template=”Blank Slate”
Add whatever content you want
Because there is no Title, we need set a Permalink so that is human readable, let say : your-site/blah
Publish the page
Go to the page you want to have the popup window show up on clicking a link
Add the following code :

```
<a href='' onclick='window.open("https://your-site/blah/","window-name","width=400,height=320");' target='blank'>Popup window</a>
```